# Subtracting Days from Current Date

Tags: date, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an `expression` that shows the current day, month, and year:

```
=Mid(Today(),1,9)
```

How would I display the week before the current date? So if today is `6/26/2014`, it would show `6/19/2014` in the box next to it. I tried using `DateAdd` and adding `-7` but that gave me an error.

Comment: In the expression editor you would use DateAdd("d",-7,<your_date>), but in SQL you would use DATEADD(DAY, -7, <your_date>);

Comment: I tried this expression and it worked perfectly fine .. 
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,Today())

Comment: I would suggest to create a function using custom code in report and pass the date value and return expected value from that function. Wrap it with Try Catch block and return the exception as string in case it fails. Then you can check what is an error exactly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried the following expression in ReportBuilder and it worked fine...

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,Today())
```

In case you still get an error then I would suggest to create a function using custom code in report and pass the date value and return expected value from that function. Wrap it with Try Catch block and return the exception as string in case it fails. Then you can check what is an error exactly. Take a look at the function here...

' Call following function in expression like this `=Code.SubstractDate(YourDateValue)`

```
Function SubstractDate(InputDate As DateTime) As String
Try
   Return =DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,InputDate).ToString() ' Use your own format as you like
Catch ex as Exception
 Return ex.Message
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a bit more information regarding DateAdd function:

To get the date of week before, just reduce 7 days (add number -7) in the function like:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -7,Today())
```

You can add/reduce year, quarter month etc. in a similar way as shown below. Just change the number to the required length

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Quarter,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.DayOfYear,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.WeekDay,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute,-1,Today())

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Second,-1,Today())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing K D's answer DateInterval.Day by "d" and Today() by FORMAT(Cdate(today), "MM/dd/yyyy") would help